# Kernel Panic when booting into Mac OS. iMac 27 2017

Tags: bootcamp, recovery, internet, kernel-panic, internet-recovery

A few months ago, I was using the iMac and opened up spotlight search and there was my first ever kernel panic. It restarted then I logged back in and everything works fine. 
(The report is at the end)

After a month, I had 2 QuickTime player windows open, a Final Cut Pro window, a Chrome tab with only 8GB RAM. A kernel panic happened and I was able to log back in and opened up chrome and started watching a YouTube video, after a minute or so, another kernel panic happened and another one after reaching the login screen. It kept restarting (it's like the Kernal panic countdown started getting shorter to the point where it wouldn't even reach the login screen. After a few restarting, it showed a ''prohibitory sign'', after 30 seconds it shut off. I tried booting into Recovery mode but no luck. I tried booting into internet recovery, the globe did a quick spin and went into the same apple logo and progress bar and it did a kernel panic. I pressed Alt at startup and selected my BootCamp drive (Windows) it booted with no problems at all.

It's been a few months since my last interaction with Mac OS. Every time 
 I boot I have to hold down alt and select BootCamp. I'm currently writing this post on my BootCamp drive with no problems at all. Video editing works better than Mac OS. The reason I got an iMac is to use mac os and not windows or I could've just got a PC instead. So I would like to fix the Mac OS portion of this iMac.

SPECS:
Mac OS Version: 10.14.2 (I think)
iMac 5K 27'' 2017
3.8GHZ core i5
8GB Ram
2 TB Fusion Drive
Radeon Pro 580 (8GB) Graphics Card

[Kernel Panic Report](https://pastebin.com/EktiDgwV)

Comment: Standard procedure- remove all non-Apple kexts first. Virtualbox is out of date, Soundflower has been crashy since Mavericks.

Comment: But I can't access Mac OS. I only have access to Bootcamp

Comment: Try the hardware test, hold D at boot chimes. Run both the short & long tests.

Comment: Ok, it says No issues found

Answer (score 1):

First you should try removing any third-party, external peripherals you have connected to your iMac. If the problem persists, and your observations are correct, then you have a hardware error with your iMac. You should contact Apple or the dealer for repairs. You can also use the built-in hardware test to search for errors, but be aware that it only catches a small subset of possible errors.

The reason I say this is that when you boot into Internet Recovery, it is not using any information from your macOS installation or from your hard drive in general. If that kernel panics during boot, you have a hardware problem.

There are many possible reasons as to why this seems to only affect macOS and not Windows in Bootcamp. You could be lucky that you're not hitting the faulty hardware, and it could be that Windows in general does not use that portion of the hardware - or that flaws in that piece of hardware is inconsequential for Windows (or at least you haven't noticed the problem yet).

The actual defective hardware could be many things, but it is often faulty RAM or similar component. The hard drive is not used for Internet Recovery, but there's a small chance that a defective hard drive could interfere anyways - however, in that case you shouldn't be able to run Windows from the same drive.

Comment: I went into Apple diagnostics just now and it says No issues found

Comment: It is only able to find a small subset of possible errors.

Comment: So what should I do? You're saying it's a hardware problem but I made a copy of this question on another site and they're saying I should make a USB Bootable drive because I have errors on my drive.

Comment: If your observations are correct, you have an hardware error. You’re saying that you have kernel panics when running Internet Recovery. In Internet Recovery nothing is loaded from disk, so it cannot be a software error. If you have detached all peripherals - then it is a hardware error. Try removing the disk and starting Internet Recovery...

Comment: By disk I mean the physical disk drive(s) - i.e. with a fusion disk like yours it is a hard disk drive and a SSD. They're not easily removable, so if you don't have experience here - I would advise against doing it yourself. Just take it to the vendor or Apple for repairs.

Comment: Repairing the drive will have no effect. If you can boot from a bootable USB drive, you should also be able to boot from Internet Recovery Mode - unless you have a hardware problem. Which is the point. But yes, you can definitely try repairing the drive - but I would definitely take a full backup before doing any changes to the drive. As it sounds like you have a hardware problem, a drive repair from Disk Utility might actually destroy data instead of help the problem. Therefore ensure backups before doing anything!

Comment: I have a bootable flash drive, not sure if it works, but when I turned on the computer I pressed alt and booted into the USB Flash Drive and there was an instant kernel panic message but it didn't actually reboot but instead continued the boot sequence to the USB Flash Drive. It took a whole 2 minutes to fully reach the progress bar and it reset and this time it filled up faster and loaded to a blank dark grey screen with 30 seconds of beach balling. Then there was a screen saying that the install packages were missing blah blah. Only the apple logo was visible in the top bar.

Comment: I tried shutting the computer down by clicking on the apple logo and pressed shut down but then an annoying startup thing popped up and the utility tab appeared and I tried clicking on it but it was just beach balling for a minute, just straight up annoying. So eventually it shut down.

Comment: Could you add the contents of some of those kernel panics, you've seen, to this question? I just noticed now that you have one kernel panic text attached, and this seems to indicate a problem with the Fusion Drive. I.e. for example a problem with the SSD part of the Fusion Drive, which would affect macOS, but not Windows. However it could also happen due to a RAM problem. It would be very interesting to get more kernel panic texts, so that we can see if it always fails with regards to the Fusion Drive, or it is random places.

Comment: The panic I attached was my first ever kernel ever on any iMac I have/ on this iMac and it happened a month before the Kernel Panic Loop. I am not able to get the panic report for the panic loop because it won’t even go farther then half on the progress bar. 
Anyway I can get the report from BootCamp?

Comment: I was moving into a different house. When I was turning on my iMac, I didn't use my surge protector, but instead plugged it directly to my wall. When I turned on my machine, I forgot to plug in my keyboard, so pressing alt did nothing, but it booted right into the login screen of MAC OS!! I was screaming, but then I quickly plugged in my keyboard and logged in. There was zero kernel panics!

Comment: I currently have chrome open on Mac OS, but I'm too scared to do anything else because, what if the panics comeback? What should I do in this case, in terms of diagnosing , the screen savers are popping up fine, Final cut pro notifications popped up that my video was exported before the panic attack. I could open up launchpad and do stuff smoothly. Also, I checked my available storage, it said 1.1 TB available, whereas before the panic attack, it was 300 or 600 GB. It feels really weird because, this drive hasn't been touched in over 9 MONTHS.

Comment: I would take a backup immediately!

Comment: I did, for the stuff I needed, I uploaded it to google drive.I opened console from spotlight, it works perfectly fine.Disk utility, launchpad and chrome works fine. Shutting down and turning on works fine. But I'm kinda scared to open any other apps.